# ORA-00936: missing expression, although there seems to be no missing expression (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to calculate the ratio of two sums, one of which has a `where` clause, so I decided to utilize subqueries:

```
select round(100.0*credit.luotot/all.kaikki) as CPROS
from 
(select sum(ordered.totalprice) as kaikki from ordered) all,
(select sum(ordered.totalprice) as luotot from ordered where ordered.paymentby = 'credit') credit
```

However, running this query throws

> ORA-00936: missing expression

and I don't understand why.

Comment: ALL is a reserved word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`all` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) in [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle). You should use a name that isn't, such as `all_ordered`:

```
select round(100.0*credit.luotot/all_ordered.kaikki) as CPROS
from 
(select sum(ordered.totalprice) as kaikki from ordered) all_ordered,
(select sum(ordered.totalprice) as luotot from ordered where ordered.paymentby = 'credit') credit
```

EDIT:
BTW, you can achieve the desired result with a `case` expression so you won't need to use subqueries:

```
SELECT  ROUND(100.0 * 
              SUM(totalprice) / 
              SUM(CASE paymentby 
                  WHEN 'credit' THEN totalprice 
                  ELSE 0 END) as CPROS
FROM    ordered
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `ALL` as an `ALIAS` that way. Change it to something else :

```
SELECT round(100.0*credit.luotot/total.kaikki) AS cpros 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT SUM(ORDERED.totalprice) AS kaikki 
              FROM   ordered) total, 
       ( 
              SELECT SUM(ordered.totalprice) AS luotot 
              FROM   ORDERED 
              WHERE  ordered.paymentby = 'credit') credit
/
```

`ALL` is a reserved word in Oracle. It is a comparison condition is used to compare a value to a list or subquery.

Also, you should make use of **`subquery factoring`** i.e. the `WITH` clause, rather than redefining the subquery multiple times. Read http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php